# How to set java package for persisted entities in Eclipse JPA

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I have a JPA Eclipse project and SQL connection. How can I edit persistence.xml so when I export tables from MySQL DB (JPA tools -> generate Entities From tables), the corresponding classes will be placed in a specific java package? 
Currently my tables are placed in default 'model' package.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit odd.. while exporting, you have to click 'Next' button until customize defaults window, and there is an option to change. However, default value was not set to model but to my other package, and that confused me when i was checking w/o exporting. If you just press finish without clicking next it will export to the 'model' package.